# Eclipse (Juno) hangs on JSF EL Expression Auto Complete

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, eclipse-juno, performance

I am working with Eclipse Juno and a JSF 2.1 Project.

Auto-Complete for EL Expressions inside a Facelets file is excruciatingly slow. 
Slow to the point where if I try to auto-complete a JSF Bean with 20 or so methods, Eclipse editor will hang for 10-15 seconds until I see the members/properties list.

The way I see it I have 2 solutions, I don't know how to implement neither, so help on any would help. (With preference to the first)

1. Resolve the slowness problem. My guess is Eclipse is doing a bunch of stuff I don't need when I press ctrl-space and if could disable those that should make it faster. (Educated Guess)
2. Disable Auto-Complete for El Expressions completely and install JBoss Tools (Which I must say, works flawlessly but when in conjunction with the native auto-complete support, It still hangs on every ctrl-space).

So, either solution would help - Resolve slowness **or** Disable Auto-Complete all together.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I haven't tried Juno yet, but if this is true, this would really be awkward. Have you reported an issue at bugs.eclipse.org?

Comment: Perhaps you just have a slow or outdated computer?  It is not uncommon for Eclipse to piggishly consume over 500MB of memory.

Comment: @BalusC Tried a clean install of eclipse. Computer is resourcefull (Runs everything else fine in eclipse).
What I currently do - Disable the facet of JSF in the project and leave just jBoss tools on. This works perfectly. JBoss is auto-completing quickly and efficiently..

Comment: @maple_shaft (see previous comment).Seems like Eclipse is doing something very inefficiently. With a very light bean (1 method), it's pretty quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me :

- Window -> Show View -> Error Log
- if there are errors about a timeout to find javadoc for the JRE, do this :

  - Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
- remove the JRE, add the JDK
  (or maybe you can configure the Java-doc for the JRE)

Answer (score 5):

Well.. Since no one is answering..

I removed the JSF facet and installed jboss tools.
Works fine since I build my project from outside of eclipse.

There are some caveats like support for certain content but all in all that's the "lesser of evils" solution.

Comment: It solved the slowness problem for me, upvoted. Do you remember what kind of content you had trouble with after applying this solution? I wouldn't be able to tell, since the combination of Eclipse's Web Tools and JBoss Tools works erratically for me most of the time.

Comment: This is still true for Eclipse Oxygen.2.
Using JSF project facet causes hang for 10-20 s, disabling it and using JBoss tools is immediate.

Comment: Too long ago :) sorry